# What is a -ckt mainline kernel?

Tags: kernel, versions

I just saw `v3.16.7-ckt1-utopic` on http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D and found a [related anouncement](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-scsi/msg80367.html) promising information about `-ckt` kernels in [the 
ExtendedStable kernel article of the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/ExtendedStable). I don't find any mention of what a `-ckt` kernel is (substring isn't contained in the wiki article) except if the reference from the announcement means that `-ckt` is an extended-stable-kernel (feels like too many corners to think around to make the connection to the suffix). Why would `v3.16.7-ckt1-utopic` be the only `-ckt` kernel then?

What does `-ckt` in the version mean?

Comment: This might be the fastest accepted answer I ever got :D  lol. btw: it does not explain WHY but I assume they wanted to idenify who worked on what kernel(?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Canonical Kernel Team".

[Found it on the debian mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2014/11/msg00154.html) and it also explains why 3.16 is the only kernel at the moment that has it.

> In addition, I would like to announce a change in the kernel numbering
>   scheme that we will be using: we are adding the string '-ckt'
>   ('Canonical Kernel Team') to the kernel version.  So, for example,
>   kernel '3.16.7.1' becomes '3.16.7-ckt1'.
>
> Note that this change applies *only* to the 3.16 kernel, although in
>   the future we may consider doing it for other kernels we are currently
>   maintaining.
>
> Cheers,
>   -- Luís